# Angular: how to return the first successful response from the list of http requests

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a list of servers urls and making sequential http requests to them in a loop. When the success response arrives from the current request I want to break the loop and not to call all other servers. Could someone advice me how this could be handled in Angular/RxJS? Something like:

```
  getClientData() {
        for(let server of this.httpsServersList) {
                    var myObservable = this.queryData(server)
                        .pipe(
                            map((response: any) => {
                                const data = (response || '').trim();
                                
                                if(data && this.dataIsCorrect(data)) {
                                    return data; // **here I want to break from the loop!**
                                }
                            })
                        );
                    return myObservable;
                 }
  }     

  private queryData(url: string) {        
     return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
```

Comment: Instead of forloop you should use RxJS race
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race

Comment: @Minapaulis With race there will be a single request or just the first arrived successful one?

Comment: I do not think that race is a good one cause it will break if any of the observables throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it's better to avoid using a `for` loop for subscribing to multiple observables. It might lead to multiple open subscriptions. Common function used for this case is RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin). But given your specific condition, I'd suggest using RxJS [`from`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from) function with [`concatMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap) operator to iterator each element in order and [`takeWhile`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeWhile) operator with it's `inclusive` argument set to `true` (thanks @Chris)  to stop based on a condition and to return the last value.

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, filter, map, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

getClientData(): Observable<any> {
  return from(this.httpsServersList).pipe(
    concatMap((server: string) => this.queryData(server)),
    map((response: any) => (response || '').trim()),
    filter((data: string) => !!data && this.dataIsCorrect(data)) // <-- ignore empty or undefined and invalid data
    takeWhile(((data: string) =>                                 // <-- close stream when data is valid and condition is true
      !data || !this.dataIsCorrect(data)
    ), true)
  );
}
```

Note: Try to tweak the condition inside the `takeWhile` predicate to match your requirement.

Edit 1: add `inclusive` argument in `takeWhile` opeartor

Edit 2: add additional condition in the `filter` operator

Comment: if the value is not valid anyway I will receive an event with the value

Comment: you need to add the second parameter in takeWhile (takeWhile(condition, true) the true causing the predicate to return false will also be emitted) and you need to add a filter after takeWhile to check if the value is valid

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the point above `inclusive` parameter of `takeWhile`. I've updated the answer. About the invalid value, yes the OP didn't seem to mention they don't need the invalid values, so I've left them in. The `filter` operator's predicate could be extended to ignore invalid values.

Comment: @MichaelD Could you update 'filter' in your answer? I don't need invalid values. I'm going to accept your answer. One more question: does it matter whether filter is before 'takeWhile' or after? Thanks.

Comment: @SimonD: I've updated the answer to ignore invalid data. About the order, it doesn't actually a difference in regards to the data emitted. But if the `takeWhile` is above the `filter`, the conditions would be evaluated twice since `takeWhile` doesn't really stop the notification from being emitted. For that reason, I'd have the `filter` above `takeWhile`.

Answer (score 0):

In angular we rely on RxJS operators for such complex calls
If you want to to call all of them in parallel then once one of them is fulfilled or rejected to cancel the other calls you should use
RxJS race learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race
Or without RxJS you could use Promise.race

However if you want to call them in parallel and wait until first fulfilled "not rejected" or all of them rejected this is the case for Promise.any
Unfortunately no RxJS operator for it but on the follwoing article you could see how to implement this custom operator for Promise.any and an example for that operator
https://tmair.dev/blog/2020/08/promise-any-for-observables/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [race](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race) because it will call all URLs in parallel, but you can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) with recursive implementation

```js
import { of, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

function getClientData(urls: string[]) {
  // check if remaining urls
  if (!urls.length) throw throwError(new Error('all urls have a error'));  ;

  return queryData(urls[0]).pipe(
    switchMap((response) => {
      const data = (response || '').trim();
                                
      if(data && this.dataIsCorrect(data))
        // if response is correct, return an observable with the data
        // for that we use of() observable
        return of(data)

      // if response is not correct, we call one more time the function with the next url
      return getClientData(urls.slice(1))
    }),
    catchError(() => getClientData(urls.slice(1)))
  );
}

function queryData(url: string): Observable<unknown> {        
  return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a subject like this

```
responseArrived=new Subject();
```

and after pipe add takeuntil like this

```
 var myObservable = this.queryData(server).pipe(takeUntil(responseArrived),map...
```

and in the line of code return data just call

```
responseArrived.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only condition is that you cancel requests once at least one response is received, can't just simply unsubscribe from the observable returned from the `HttpClient` call?

```
  getData() {
    const subscriptions = [];
    [
      'https://reqres.in/api/products/1',
      'https://reqres.in/api/products/2',
      'https://reqres.in/api/products/3',
    ].forEach((url, i) => {
      subscriptions[i] = this.getClientData(url).subscribe(() => {
        // Unsubscribe
        subscriptions.forEach((v, j) => {
          if (j !== i) {
            console.log('Unsubscribe from ', j);
            v.unsubscribe();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
  private getClientData(url: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        const data = (response || '').trim();
        if (data && true) return data;
        return null;
      })
    );
  }
```